# how to give file path which reside in Git Repository in my java code

Tags: java, git, path

My log file reside in Path: `/cucumber/log/testlog.log` (GIT REPOSITORY Path)

When i use `../cucumber/log/testlog.log` (it works fine in local repository).
But with remote Repository it did not work and gives Exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\cucumber\master\log\testlog.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

What to use? Kindly suggest.

Comment: git is completely irrelevant. What matters is where the files are located at runtime, from which location you execute your program, and of course, its code.

Comment: i am triggering the Build request via Jenkins. and in the Code itself i check for the variable value if the time is greater than 10 sec i make a smtp connection and trigger a mail via java code. Giving  
         // attachments
         String[] attachFiles = new String[1];
         attachFiles[0] = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abhishekgaur4feb/cucumber/master/log/testlog.log";       but when it is trigger via jenkins it always give error: (The system cannot find the path specified